# Is this a VS2008 bug? Functional style variable initialisation

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

In the code below, the line

```
const char * const * eNames (names+cntNames);
```

results in a [C2061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yha416c7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) error in Visual Studio 2008:

> syntax error : identifier 'identifier' - 
>   The compiler found an identifier where it wasn't expected.
>   Make sure that identifier is declared before you use it.
>   An initializer may be enclosed by parentheses.
>   To avoid this problem, enclose the declarator in parentheses or make it a typedef.
>   This error could also be caused when the compiler detects an expression as a class
>   template argument; use typename to tell the compiler it is a type.

If I change to

```
const char * const * eNames = names+cntNames;
```

it doesn't complain.  Is this a compiler bug?  If not, why the complaint?

My About box says: Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

My colleague with GCC does not see this error.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace ns1 {

   struct str_eq_to
   {
      str_eq_to(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {}
      bool operator()(const char* x) const { return s_.compare(x)==0; }
      const std::string& s_;
   };

   static bool getNameIndex(const char * const * names, size_t cntNames, const std::string& nm, int &result)
   {
      const char * const * eNames (names+cntNames);  //VS2008 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'names'
      const char * const * p = std::find_if(names, eNames, str_eq_to(nm));
      if(p==eNames) return false;
      result = p-names;
      return true;
   }

} //namespace ns1


int main() {

   const char * const names[] = {"Apple", "Orange","Plum"};
   std::string str = "Plum";
   int res;

   ns1::getNameIndex(names, 3, str, res);
   std::cout << str << " is at index " << res << std::endl; 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: VS 2008 is five years old, positively geriatric in compiler years, and (obviously) hasn't kept up with developments in C++ since then.  I recommend you download VS 2012 Express (zero-cost, requires registration) and try it there.  If it works, you can assume VS 2008 was wrong.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a most-vexing-parse related problem. Try a second set of parens: `const char * const * eNames ((names+cntNames));`

Comment: @MarkB - VS2008 then doesn't like double brackets and get C2059 for each bracket.

Comment: @Zack I just tried compiling in VS 2012 Ultimate and I encountered the same error.

Comment: Avoid making statements look like function prototypes and the compiler will be happy.

Comment: Please improve the title so that future visitors to the site with the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most definitely a compiler bug. Witness:

```
extern char** a;
typedef char* cp;
char** c(a);      // error
cp* c1(a);        // no error
char** c2(c1);    // error
cp* n(0);         // no error
char** n2(0);     // error
```